# Make a JTextArea appear in my game view

Tags: java, swing, game-center

I am developing a simple game where have to write words. So I taught to make a TextArea where the words typed goes, to this I need a scroll to can see all words. But i have a render method that have this:

```
public void onRender(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(imgBG, 0,0, null); //draws my background
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(titulo);
    g.drawString("Type the Word!", 260, 240);
    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);

    for(int i=0;i < wordFind.length();i++)
    {
        g.fillRect(inicioTraco+(60*i),yTraco,40,10);
    }
    if(tag_s == true)
    {
        tag_s = false;
        g.setFont(titulo);
        g.drawString("s",posicao, 100);
    }
    this.getMainWindow().add(new JTextArea("Test",10,20));

}
```

getMainWindow is a method that return my main JFrame, and i put this JTextArea to show the words.

But it is not appearing in my game.

I taught to make a white rect (fillrect) but it will not have scoll.

So I don't know what to do. Can someone clear my mind?

thanks.

Comment: Swing components have there own means for painting and shouldn't be included in your paint process. Are you using a BufferStrategy?

Comment: Yeah, I am using, so how can i paint this?

Comment: A `BufferStrategy` and Swing components don't work together, they use different rendering techniques, that's the point - You use a `BufferStrategy` when you want to control the paint process, but Swing uses it's own

Comment: So what can i dot in this case? Can i make a something with scroll and BufferStrategy?

Comment: Sure you can, you'll have to make it from scratch and implement it yourself though